# writing concurrently to one byte in memory

Tags: c++, concurrency, corruption

We have a class in c++, which has `unsigned char` field flag.

```
class XYZ
{
  ... some fields..
  unsigned char someFlag;
  ... some more fields
};
```

On same object of `XYZ`, we are writing `0` and `1` boolean on `someFlag` from multiple threads and reading from all threads without any synchronization primitives like locks or atomic. Ideally, this would toggle between 0 and 1. `someFlag` is changed on every request and even if we see it enabled/disabled temporarily for few requests it is ok.

Is it possible that it might corrupt fields next to `someFlag` ?

If yes, What if we pad `someFlag` with 4 bytes before and after ?

I am thinking of using `std::atomic<bool>` or similar data type.. but i need to convince author of library to use it by providing example of data races that can happen.

Is reading from `std::atomic` with `relaxed` as fast as normal read and it avoids other compiler optimizations that can cause weird issues when writing/reading variable concurrently without synchronization ?

Comment: The compiler should already include padding depending on any switches you set to the contrary (like packing).

Comment: would compiler add padding if i have `UCHAR someFlag; UCHAR someFlag2; .. 8 more flags ` ? i don't think so..

Comment: All depends on your processor's word size or the size that the processor is efficient at.

Comment: It depends on the definition of `UCHAR` -- that's not a standard type.  If it is defined as a type that is atomic on your target, then all will be fine.

Comment: Why not use `std::atomic <UCHAR>`?  Then you know you are safe.

Comment: i moved from `UCHAR` to `unsigned char`.. @ChrisDodd What do you mean by `atomic` ? atomic has different meanings in different contexts.. just want to understand your point..

Comment: I am in pull request discussion with someone .. then they don't want to use `std::atomic`.. i need some strong case to defend this.. 
I think if i read with relaxed semantics from std::atomic it will still be fast and avoid other compiler tricks that can cause issues ?

Comment: @AshishNegi are you looking for the "language-lawyer" perspective on this (i.e. what the C++ language spec specified must happen), or more of the "practical use" perspective (i.e. what behavior you are actually likely to observe on modern/popular hardware)?  The answers between the two may be different.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner i am interested in practical real world .. but this code will run on linux, windows server OS across multiple hardware, in VMs and baremetal..

Comment: Why not simply use `std::atomic_flag`?  It's [guaranteed lock-free](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag#top).  Aside from that you're accessing a potentially non-atomically modifiable location from multiple threads concurrently.  That's UB as far as I'm aware (unless your compiler vendor can guarantee otherwise for the case in point).

Comment: @AshishNegi: "atomic" as defined by the spec -- so at least `std::atomic` types.  Other types may be atomic, it depends on the implementation.  On *most* implementations `char` will be atomic (so `std::atomic<char>` is the same as `char`)

Comment: @G.M. About your note on `potentially non-atomically modifiable` .. Is `unsigned char (1 byte)` also non atomically modifiable ? Would fields near it can get corrupted ?

Comment: @G.M. `std::atomic_flag` would require `while (test_set()`.. 
For my current situation, shouldn't volatile be fast and also prevent compiler optimizations that cause bugs? 

I am not worried about all threads seeing the updated value at a time.. as reqs are always coming in .. I am more worried about what else can go wrong ? https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you have written thread safe application with proper locks when writes are made, it wouldn't cause any issue.

Assuming you mean for a non-threaed safe application, would there be an issue? There could be but will not corrupt any other fields.